# For what step disturbance value the system will become unstable?

Tags: control, stability

I am new to control theory and have difficulties about this question
[image: control system scheme]

R is the input, Td is the disturbance, C is the output
Given that G1=K/(s^2+A*s), where K is the gain and A is a parameter greater than zero.
The question is, for what value of the step disturbance the system can become unstable?
How do I solve this?

Comment: I suggest you to use MathJax for better presentation of mathematical equations - https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/how-can-i-format-mathematical-expressions-here-using-mathjax

Answer (score 5):

The stability is a property of the linear systems themselves, hence there is no meaning in considering stability as regarded with the input disturbance $T_d$.

To verify if the closed-loop system $C/T_d$ is stable/unstable, you ought to compute the roots of the characteristic polynomial.

Given that
$$
\frac{C}{T_d} = - \frac{s^2+As}{s^2+As+K},
$$
the roots of $s^2+As+K$ − poles of the closed-loop system − are:
$$
s_{1,2} = \frac{-A \pm \sqrt{A^2-4K}}{2}.
$$
For $C/T_d$ to be unstable, at least one pole needs to have a positive real part, thus $K<0$.